# Are there any free open-source custom firmwares for e-ink devices?

Tags: e-ink, ebook-readers, firmware, customization

I'm curious if there are custom firmwares for e-ink devices similar to what Rockbox ([website](http://www.rockbox.org/), [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rockbox)) is for digital audio players.

Comment: This may possibly be to be too broad as there are many very different e-ink devices. e-Ink is a display technology, not an architecture

Comment: I think OP was purposefully broad because they aren't even sure where to start, except by asking. And asking is where good ideas start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[KOReader](https://github.com/koreader/koreader/wiki) is an ereading software available for several devices and platforms. Quoted from [Mobileread wiki](https://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/KOReader):

> KOReader is a document viewer for Linux based E Ink devices. Currently
>   there are versions for Kindle, Kobo, PocketBook, and Android devices.

The installation procedure depends on the device. Support forums are available on [Mobileread](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/forumdisplay.php?f=276).

[image]

Answer (score 9):

It depends on specific device and its architecture.

Those that are built on top of Android, typically tend to get AOSP ports, e.g. [Nook](https://www.google.com/search?q=aosp%20nook&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) (here's [Simple Touch instructions](http://www.alexroddie.com/2013/06/android-on-nook-simple-touch-part-2.html)), or [Kindles](https://www.google.com/search?q=aosp%20kindle%20fire&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficia) - the latter even has CyanogenMod ROM.

[Sony PRST 1](https://www.google.com/search?q=Sony%20PRS-T1%20android&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial) was hacked to expose [full underlying rooted Android](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?t=184646) but I'm not sure if AOSP based ROM is available for it - [this might be it](http://sonyfmngr.sourceforge.net/prsT1.htm).

I'm not sure if there are any non-Android-based mainstream eInk readers - most of the ones I heard of (which is not a lot) seem to be Android under the covers and thus can be opened up (e.g. see [Kobe Glo](http://www.geeky-gadgets.com/kobo-glo-e-reader-transformed-into-full-android-tablet-by-hackers-05-11-2013/)).

Comment: But... neither the Nook nor the Kindle Fire is an e-ink device as *the question specifically asked*.

Comment: @NathanOsman - http://www.barnesandnoble.com/p/nook-simple-touch-barnes-noble/1102344735. I thought that was e-ink? I'm unsure of the varieties of Kindles, but was under impression that they were all Android-based. I'll check.

Comment: @NathanOsman - Nook, I can confirm. This article on rooting it confirms e-Ink: http://www.alexroddie.com/2013/06/android-on-nook-simple-touch-part-2.html

Answer (score 3):

There is a project, called [PRS+](https://code.google.com/p/prs-plus/), for older Sony PRS devices (PRS-300, PRS-505, PRS-600, PRS-350, PRS-650, PRS-950).

Comment: Link broken, loos like this is an archive of the project: https://code.google.com/archive/p/prs-plus/

Answer (score 0):

XDA Developers don't have the e-Ink Kindle, but they have a page for the Nook Touch.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/nook-touch

Check out the "Android Development" thread.

Answer (score 0):

Look to inactive project [OpenInkpot](http://morgue.openinkpot.org/) ([2](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenInkpot), [3](http://wiki.mobileread.com/wiki/Openinkpot)).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [crowdfunding campaign](https://www.indiegogo.com/projects/13-3-inch-android-e-reader#/) for an e-ink device that says they will release the firmware as free software.

> We intend on making the firmware for the 13.3 inch e-reader available to the entire community.

I have no affiliation with the campaign or the people behind it.